# How can I get an Azure AD security group name by ObjectID in ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to obtain and AAD group name from its object ID using:

```
reference(parameters('groupId')).displayName
```

But I get the error:

```
The template reference <groupId> is not valid.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can only reference Azure resources using the `reference()` function, not Azure AD entities. this is not possible. you have to do this outside of the template and pass the display name to the template.

Comment: From within the ARM template I need both the AAD group id and its display name. So I understand that the only way is to pass both as parameters, right?

Comment: yep, azure ad is a different api, arm templates dont have access to that, unfortunately